# How to read all data from .lbl file

Tags: c#, file-handling

I have One lable file which contain barcode sticker n its values, I want to read that file and copy that file,
So ,I am using below function. Its work, but its very time consuming..!!
So, do u have any idea how to read all the data of lbl file rather than read data bit by bit which i am doing.
So , i can increse my performance.

```
    public void storeLbl(string path)
    {

            lblData = ""; 


            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
            {

                int pos = 0;


                int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                while (pos < length)
                {

                    int v = b.ReadInt32();
                    if (lblData.ToString() == "")
                    {
                        lblData = v.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblData = lblData + "," + v.ToString(); // Store Lbl Data in database


                    }

                    pos += sizeof(int);

                }
                b.Close(); 
    }   
   }
```

Second Function Which copy .lbl file with help from database value
//getting lblData value from Database

```
public void getLbl()
{

            string[] store = lblData .Split(',');

            int length = store.Length;
            storeval = new int[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                storeval[i] = Convert.ToInt32(store[i]);

            }


            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(NewPath, FileMode.Create)))// Create Copy of .lbl file
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    w.Write(storeval[i]);

                    Console.WriteLine(storeval[i]);

                }
                w.Close();  

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
byte[] allData = binaryreader1.ReadBytes(int.MaxValue);
```

to read all the data.

And write that byte array directly to a binarywriter.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @cadsjo Answer I got the Solution,
Now My Function is!!

using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("Original file Path", FileMode.Open)))
            {

```
            int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
            byte[] allData = b.ReadBytes(length);

            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("New File Path", FileMode.Create)))
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    w.Write(allData[i]);

                }

            }
        }
```